# PHPMailer failed in sending email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Trying to send the email form information to a particular email account via php mailer, after validating all the information i've received the information in data variable in validate_email function.

where I have applied the php mailer code and want to send all the information of data variable to a particular email account.

but its shows me error

```
<?php

   $name = $email = $query = "";
   $name_err = $email_err = $query_err = "";

   if ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty ( $_POST ["name"] )) {
        $name_err = 'Please Enter Your Name';
    } else {
        $name = validate_email ( $_POST ["name"] );
    }
    if (empty ( $_POST ["email"] )) {
        $email_err = 'Please Enter Your Email Id';
    } else {
        $email = validate_email ( $_POST ["email"] );

        if (! filter_var ( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) {
            $email_err = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }
    if (empty ( $_POST ["query"] )) {
        $query_err = 'Please type your query';
    } else {
        $query = validate_email ( $_POST ["query"] );
    }
    }

    function validate_email($data) {
    $data = trim ( $data );
    $data = stripslashes ( $data );
    $data = htmlspecialchars ( $data );


    $subject = "Visitor Query";
    $from = "007shiva007@gmail.com"; // example a@b.com
    $password = '************';

    //require ("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
    require ("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    require ("phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer ();

    $mail->IsSMTP ();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // sets SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->Username = $from; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = $password; // SMTP password

    $mail->AddAddress ( "partyushgoyal@gmail.com" );
    // $mail->AddAddress ( "choudharypadam3@gmail.com" );
    // $mail->AddReplyTo ( "choudharypadam3@gmail.com", "Reply Address" );

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $data;
    // $mail->AltBody = 'Padma Industries';
    $mail->From = $from;
    //$mail->FromName = 'Padmaindustries.in';
    $mail->ContentType = "text/html";

    $result = $mail->Send ();

    //header ( "location: index.php" );

    //return $data;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Check with port number

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: mail is being send but a message showing up at the bottom

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\s2sproject\index.php:247) in C:\xampp\htdocs\s2sproject\inc\footer.php on line 71

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class phpmailerException in C:\xampp\htdocs\s2sproject\PHPMailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 3471

Comment: The first error has nothing todo with PHPMailer. You try to set http headers after you already outputted something. The second error means, that the file, in which the class is declared is required more than one time. Use require_once instead of require.

Comment: now its writing a long report something like 2015-02-03 13:45:36 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2015-02-03 13:45:36 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2015-02-03 13:45:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
how to get rid of it

Comment: and please one more thing i am receiving all the form data in 3 different emails like first i receive name then email the receiving query ? 
how to get it once all together ?

Comment: Why have you commented out the autoloader?? It won't cause the double load problem you've created for yourself. It looks like you have based your code on an old example - are you using latest from GitHub?

Comment: no i changed it back to autoloader

Comment: can you answer one of the problem why i am receiving the who email data in 3 different emails, first name then email id of sender and the query ?

Comment: it seems worked for me now